# Is there any AWS lambda to lambda payload transfer size limitation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have implemented two public lambda. One lambda (A) generates JSON and sends it to another lambda (B) asynchronously for further processing. Note that both lambdas are public and not inside VPC. When lambda A sends payload to lambda B, it gives below error. Now the question is, is there any limitation of max byte transfer between two lambdas? If yes, what is that max size? Can it be increased?

```
 RequestEntityTooLargeException: 293326 byte payload is too large for the Event invocation type (limit 262144 bytes),
            at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27),
            at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8),
            at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20),
            at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10),
            at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14),
            at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10),
            at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12),
            at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10,
            at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9),
            at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
```

Comment: That's a large payload. Perhaps you could upload it to S3 and have the completion of the upload trigger your 2nd Lambda function?

Comment: Another option that we've used in a project is to make the request to the Lambda via API Gateway, that replies back with an S3 pre-signed URL that the client then uploads to.  You could do the same thing Lambda-to-Lambda.  It's a bit more complex than just calling the Lambda but AWS has set their limits for some good reason, at least from their perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda request size is limited to 6MB for sync requests or 256KB (your issue) for async requests:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Under some cases these limits can be increased.  The referenced AWS page has a link to the Support Center which is where you would make such a request.

Comment: According to that doc page, the max invocation payload size cannot be changed.

Comment: Agreed, but you can always ask.

Comment: We asked AWS and they denied to increase. Also, instead of instead of transferring payload from one lambda to other lambda, we are pushing now to S3 (there is no size limit) and reading it from S3 in second lambda. It solved our problem and we could transfer big payload with this approach.